# Using VBA If then statement to copy and paste data to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA, I need to post all PO data to another workbook with if condition, if condition on column A, from A30 to A82 if any value is greater than Zero on the said cell, then copy the data to another sheet.

Please see my code below. I need help to write the IF condition.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\XXX\DSR\LPO Auto\lpodata.xlsx")
    Worksheets("Food").Unprotect Password:="XXXXXX"

    NR = wb.Sheets("Food").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO")
        'If ActiveSheet.Range("A30").Value > 1 Then
        Range("A30:W83").Copy
        wb.Sheets("Food").Range("A" & NR).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("Food").Protect Password:="XXXXX"
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        Worksheets("PO").Range("B30:C82").Select
        Worksheets("PO").Range("B30:C82").ClearContents
        Worksheets("PO").Range("H30:H82").Select
        Worksheets("PO").Range("H30:H82").ClearContents
        ActiveWorkbook.Save

    End With


    'wb.Close savechanges:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a loop like this, this will iterate over each cell in define range :

```
For Each cell In .Range("A30:A82").Cells
    if cell.Value > 0 Then
       //your code
    end if
Next
```